# How can I get the value of an object?

Tags: javascript

```
var  body ='{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "This authorization code has been used"}'
console.log(body.error_type)
```

I want to get value of body.error_type but is showing undefined how can I get value of it.

Comment: `body` is a String, so it has no `error_type` property. Either remove the quotes around it, or parse the JSON: `JSON.parse(body).error_type`

Comment: It worked with JSON.parse. Thanks buddy

Comment: Why all those tags? There's no array, no object and it has nothing to do with C.

Answer (score 1):

You have enclosed the value with single quotes (`'`), which means that the type of `body` is `string`, not `object`. An object should be enclosed with curly braces (`{}`).

Compare the following:

```js
const someString = '{foo: "bar"}';
const anObject = {foo: "bar"};
```

For your use case:

```js
const body = {
  error_type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 400,
  error_message: 'This authorization code has been used',
};
console.log(body.error_type);
```

If you are receiving `body` from elsewhere and the value is already a string, you can parse it as an object using `JSON.parse(body)`.